# Identity function in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, identity

In functional programming is sometimes *useful* to have an [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function).
Is there a built-in or a function defined in some module that does this?

Answer (score 5):

The identity function can be simply defined as:

```
identity = lambda x: x
```

I'm not aware of this function defined in any module, but it could be a good fit for [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

Comment: Do you people think it could be good to open a *PEP*?

Comment: Although it is clean in this case, assigning a lambda to a variable is against the PEP-8 standards. So adding it to functools might actually make sense here.

Comment: The identity function is useful if you are sub-classing a class that uses a transform function as one of it's attributes and you want to be able to support a NOP function for those sub-classes that don't need one, or perhaps default the super class to identity. You can always assign None but then that requires a check for None which can interrupt a convenient generator or comprehension.